# Use mapCruncher tiles with Gmap.Net

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I used Microsoft's `MapCruncher` to slice the images into tiles and now I want to overlay those tiles into the `GMap.Net`. I tried the example but my program doesn't even start. This is what I tried but the program doesn't start. I have got all of the tiles. Now just need to bring those to GMap.

```
try
{
    int c = 0;
    int type = GMapProviders.LithuaniaTOP50Map.DbId;
    //GMaps.Instance.PrimaryCache.DeleteOlderThan(DateTime.MaxValue, type);

    var import = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Vaib\Desktop\tiles\Layer_NewLayer\", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(p => p.Contains("Layer_") && !p.Contains("black")).ToList();

    int total = import.Count;

    foreach (var i in import)
    {
        var qk = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        GMapProviders.BingMap.QuadKeyToTileXY(qk, out x, out y, out z);

        // GMapProviders.BingMap.
        Debug.WriteLine(c++ + " of " + total + ", x: " + x + ", y: " + y + ", z: " + z);

        if (!GMaps.Instance.PrimaryCache.PutImageToCache(File.ReadAllBytes(i), type, new GPoint(x, y), z))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("import: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't start? is this in a Main method?

Comment: Yes this is in MainForm(). It builds but when I hit run, nothing shows up. But I can see it running in the task manager processes.